# htaccess: redirect first folder to get param

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am very new to regular expressions and the .htaccess file of the apache webserver.

I want to rewrite a url so that the first subfolder gets converted to a GET-parameter and all the following subfolders should be left as they are...

A few examples:
**http://www.example.com/thisisthevariable**
should be rewritten to
**index.php?p=thisisthevariable**

and
**http://www.example.com/thisisthevariable/test.jpg**
should be rewritten to
**test.jpg?p=thisisthevariable**

and
**http://www.example.com/thisisthevariable/subfolder/and/another/sub/folder/123.gif**
should be rewritten to
**subfolder/and/another/sub/folder/123.gif?p=thisisthevariable**

It should work with a unlimited count of subfolders. So the whole path should be used except the first directory - this should be used as get-parameter of the destination file.

Hope, anyone understands my task and can help me :-)

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+) $2?p=$1
```

`[^/]+` matches anything that's not a forward slash, so the first part before the first `/`. The `()` capture it as a match, which is then available as `$1` (and `$2`). For more details, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this does not work... :-( When I use this RewriteRule I am getting an empty response... when I change the second line to RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+) index.php?o=$2&p$1 both GET-params gets transmitted correctly but I can not open the file

edit: Sorry, I do not get an empty result but I get the result of the index.php (which returned nothing because I only echoed the get-param). Why is my index.php opened instead of the file?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you expect from `subfolder/and/another/sub/folder/123.gif`, especially with a query string attached. How *should* that be handled...?

Comment: Well, I do have a customer portal. The customer should enter my url/customerid, for example
http://www.example.com/deceze

I want to know in my php-script which user is requesting my script and I also want to put a few images for the website design in subfolders...